# How to solve $\left ( \frac{x}{3}\right )^{n} e^{- \left ( \frac{x}{3}\right )^{n} } = \text{const.}$?

Tags: exponential-function, special-functions, lambert-w

I'm playing around with some math and I arrived at the equation:

$$\left (  \frac{x}{3}\right )^{n} e^{- \left (  x/3\right )^{n} } = \text{const.}$$

where I'm trying to solve for $x$. I think I can solve this using the Lambert W function, but I'm not sure how to apply it when the exponential term contains $x$ raised to the power $n$. Can I just apply the approach used [in this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_3)? Or is there something I'm missing.

Also, $const.$ indicates an odd-looking constant I chose to abbreviate.

Comment: Just replace $u=-(x/3)^n$ and back-substitute at the end.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, that's good advice. I'm realizing that this problem is a lot easier than I thought at first.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with

$$\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n e^{-(x/3)^n} = [\mathrm{const.}]$$

first note that the exponent of $e$ contains a negative sign. We can produce that on the outside by negating:

$$-\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n e^{-(x/3)^n} = -[\mathrm{const.}]$$

and then we see by grouping, that

$$\left[-\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n\right] e^{\left[-\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n\right]} = -[\mathrm{const.}]$$

Now that we have the same quantity both outside and inside the exponential, we can take the W:

$$-\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n = W\left(-[\mathrm{const.}]\right)$$

hence with another negation,

$$\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n = -W\left(-[\mathrm{const.}]\right)$$

and now the $n$th root

$$\frac{x}{3} = \sqrt[n]{-W\left(-[\mathrm{const.}]\right)}$$

hence, finally

$$x = 3 \sqrt[n]{-W\left(-[\mathrm{const.}]\right)}$$

is the solution.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help